# How to change the input field's text color in MaterializeCSS?

Tags: css, materialize

How can I change the text color entered into the `input-field` of `MaterializeCSS`? The [documentation](http://materializecss.com/forms.html) demonstrates how to change the color of labels or the underline, but not the color of the text.

```
 /* label color */
   .input-field label {
     color: #000;
   }
   /* label focus color */
   .input-field input[type=text]:focus + label {
     color: #000;
   }
   /* label underline focus color */
   .input-field input[type=text]:focus {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #000;
   }
   /* valid color */
   .input-field input[type=text].valid {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #000;
   }
   /* invalid color */
   .input-field input[type=text].invalid {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #000;
   }
   /* icon prefix focus color */
   .input-field .prefix.active {
     color: #000;
   }
```

The documentation also states that it's possible to modify the `sass` variables:

> Here is a CSS template for modifying input fields in CSS. With Sass,
>   you can achieve this by just changing a variable. The CSS shown below
>   is unprefixed. Depending on what you use, you may have to change the
>   type attribute selector.

But does not clarify which `sass` variables are available to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply select the input field's wrapper `<div>` by it's CSS class for changing the text color.

```
.input-field {
     color:orange;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxx2k0fq/

For changing the placeholder text color see: [Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Concerning SASS: It looks like there is only a global text color defined in Materialize, which will by default also apply to your input fields. 
In _variables.scss you can find the $off-black variable which is responsible for the color. It's applied to `<html>` tag and changing it will therefore change the text color of your whole page.

Comment: Use of `!important` is necessary here. Otherwise, the CSS won't take effect...

Answer (score 4):

Michael's answer didn't help me but this is what I got.

```
.input-field [type=text] {
    color: white;
}
```

make sure to add `[type=text]`

Comment: You can also use type=password on another line to make the password circles the same (or a different) color.

Comment: Use of `!important` is necessary here. Otherwise, the CSS won't take effect...

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
  /*============ CSS ==================== */    
    .input-field input:focus + label {
           color: white !important;
           background-color: rgb(50,50,50);
         }
         /* label underline focus color */
         .input-field input:focus {
           border-radius: 0.5rem;
           background-color: rgb(50,50,50);
         }
         .input-field #qty {
           border:none;
           border-radius: 0.5rem;
           padding: 1rem;
    /*============================ Here ===========================*/
           color: white; /* <----------- " This changes the input text color "*/
           background-color: rgb(50,50,50);
         }
```

HTML

```
  <div class="input-field" type='qty'>
        <input id="qty" type='number' label='date'style='border:none'></input>
        <label class="super" type="qty" for="supplier" style="pointer-events: none;">quantity</label>
      </div>
```

[see the result input text here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9odt1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="white-text" type="email" id="email" v-model="email">
```

change the class to what ever colour you want

Answer (score 0):

I used bellow code successfully:

```
  .input-field [type=text]{
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
}  
 
.input-field [type=email]{
  color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
}     

.input-field [type=password]{
  color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
}     

.input-field [type=tel]{
  color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```